# Why have multiple parsers?

Tags: python, argparse

I am reading through argparse docs: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html

I read through the "parents" doc for ArgumentParser and it mentioned that this is used when several parsers share common args. I am wondering, when would I need to have "several parsers" in the first place?

Comment: Do a search on `[argparse] parents` to see how others have used the feature.  It's not heavily used.  It can be handy, but rarely necessary.  Often it can be replaced by your own utility functions.

Comment: @hpaulj where do I search this?

Comment: Right here on Stackoverflow, the [argparse] tag, and `parents` string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#parents) is already fairly straightforward:

> Rather than repeating the definitions of these arguments, a single parser with all the shared arguments and passed to parents= argument to ArgumentParser can be used

One *use-case* that comes to mind is when you have a lot of scripts that do different things to a database that requires a username and password to be accessed. One of the scripts alters a table, another one changes a few permissions... but all those scripts are going to need the username and password to access the database, right?

You could have a "base" argument parser that expects (or parses) the username and password, and then have more specialized parsers with more arguments. For instance:

```
import argparse


def make_basic_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Basic parser (only username/password).',
                                     add_help=False)
    parser.add_argument('--username', type=str, help='Username to access database')
    parser.add_argument('--password', type=str, help='Password to access database')
    return parser


def alter_table_parser():
    parent = make_basic_parser()
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Alter a table', parents=[parent])
    parser.add_argument('--table', type=str, help='Table to alter')
    return parser


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = alter_table_parser()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print("Received arguments: %s" % (args))
```

Running this will result in:

```
$ python ./stack_055_A.py --username foo --password bar --table baz
Received arguments: Namespace(password='bar', table='baz', username='foo')
```

So you can reuse the *basic\parser* every time you need a username and a password.